# Get element position in the DOM on React DnD drop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I'm using React DnD and Redux (using Kea) to build a formbuilder. I've the drag & drop portion working just fine, and I've managed to dispatch an action when an element drops, and I render the builder afterwards using state that the dispatch changed. However, in order to render elements in the correct order, I (think I) need to save the dropped elements position relative to it's siblings but I'm unable to figure out anything that isn't absolutely insane. I've experimented with refs and querying the DOM with the unique ID (I know I shouldn't), but both approaches feel pretty terrible and do not even work.

Here's a simplified representation of my app structure:

```
@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
@connect({ /* redux things */ })
<Builder>
  <Workbench tree={this.props.tree} />
  <Sidebar fields={this.props.field}/>
</Builder>
```

Workbench:

```
const boxTarget = {
  drop(props, monitor, component) {
    const item = monitor.getItem()
    console.log(component, item.unique, component[item.unique]); // last one is undefined
    window.component = component; // doing it manually works, so the element just isn't in the DOM yet

    return {
      key: 'workbench',
    }
  },
}

@DropTarget(ItemTypes.FIELD, boxTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  isOver: monitor.isOver(),
  canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
}))
export default class Workbench extends Component {
  render() {
    const { tree } = this.props;
    const { canDrop, isOver, connectDropTarget } = this.props

    return connectDropTarget(
      <div className={this.props.className}>
        {tree.map((field, index) => {
          const { key, attributes, parent, unique } = field;
          if (parent === 'workbench') { // To render only root level nodes. I know how to render the children recursively, but to keep things simple...
            return (
              <Field
                unique={unique}
                key={key}
                _key={key}
                parent={this} // I'm passing the parent because the refs are useless in the Field instance (?) I don't know if this is a bad idea or not
              />
            );
          }

          return null;
        }).filter(Boolean)}
      </div>,
    )


    // ...
```

Field:

```
const boxSource = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    return {
      key: props._key,
      unique: props.unique || shortid.generate(),
      attributes: props.attributes,
    }
  },

  endDrag(props, monitor) {
    const item = monitor.getItem()
    const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult()

    console.log(dropResult);

    if (dropResult) {
      props.actions.onDrop({
        item,
        dropResult,
      });
    }
  },
}

@connect({ /* redux stuff */ })
@DragSource(ItemTypes.FIELD, boxSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
}))
export default class Field extends Component {  
  render() {
    const { TagName, title, attributes, parent } = this.props
    const { isDragging, connectDragSource } = this.props
    const opacity = isDragging ? 0.4 : 1

    return connectDragSource(
      <div
        className={classes.frame}
        style={{opacity}}
        data-unique={this.props.unique || false}
        ref={(x) => parent[this.props.unique || this.props.key] = x} // If I save the ref to this instance, how do I access it in the drop function that works in context to boxTarget & Workbench? 
      >
        <header className={classes.header}>
          <span className={classes.headerName}>{title}</span>
        </header>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <TagName {...attributes} />
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Sidebar isn't very relevant.

My state is a flat array, consisting of objects that I can use to render the fields, so I'm reordering it based on the element positions in the DOM.

```
[
  {
    key: 'field_type1',
    parent: 'workbench',
    children: ['DAWPNC'], // If there's more children, "mutate" this according to the DOM
    unique: 'AWJOPD',
    attributes: {},
  },
  {
    key: 'field_type2',
    parent: 'AWJOPD',
    children: false,
    unique: 'DAWPNC',
    attributes: {},
  },
]
```

The relevant portion of this question revolves around

```
const boxTarget = {
  drop(props, monitor, component) {
    const item = monitor.getItem()
    console.log(component, item.unique, component[item.unique]); // last one is undefined
    window.component = component; // doing it manually works, so the element just isn't in the DOM yet

    return {
      key: 'workbench',
    }
  },
}
```

I figured I'd just get the reference to the element *somehow*, but it doesn't seem to exist in the DOM, yet. It's the same thing if I try to hack with ReactDOM:

```
 // still inside the drop function, "works" with the timeout, doesn't without, but this is a bad idea
 setTimeout(() => {
    const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
    const itemEl = domNode.querySelector(`[data-unique="${item.unique}"]`);
    const parentEl = itemEl.parentNode;

    const index = Array.from(parentEl.children).findIndex(x => x.getAttribute('data-unique') === item.unique);

    console.log(domNode, itemEl, index);
  });
```

How do I achieve what I want?

Apologies for my inconsistent usage of semicolons, I don't know what I want from them. *I hate them.*

Comment: I've been working on this for too long and I'm tired, and I'm not too great on expressing myself using text anyway, so please ask for clarification if necessary instead of blindly downvoting and ruining my chances of getting an answer :)

Comment: I can't really understand what you want. Tell me what array you start with and after the drop an example of what you want it to be like.

Comment: hard to understand what you want - but i guess it's something like that: http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples-sortable-simple.html

Answer (score 5):

I think the key here is realizing that the `Field` component can be both a `DragSource` and a `DropTarget`. We can then define a standard set of drop types that would influence how the state is mutated.

```
const DropType = {
  After: 'DROP_AFTER',
  Before: 'DROP_BEFORE',
  Inside: 'DROP_INSIDE'
};
```

`After` and `Before` would allow re-ordering of fields, while `Inside` would allow nesting of fields (or dropping into the workbench).

Now, the action creator for handling any drop would be:

```
const drop = (source, target, dropType) => ({
  type: actions.DROP,
  source,
  target,
  dropType
});
```

It just takes the source and target objects, and the type of drop occurring, which will then be translated into the state mutation.

A drop type is really just a function of the target bounds, the drop position, and (optionally) the drag source, all within the context of a particular `DropTarget` type:

```
(bounds, position, source) => dropType
```

This function should be defined for each type of `DropTarget` supported. This would allow each `DropTarget` to support a different set of drop types. For instance, the `Workbench` only knows how to drop something inside of itself, not before or after, so the implementation for the workbench could look like:

```
(bounds, position) => DropType.Inside
```

For a `Field`, you could use the logic from the [Simple Card Sort example](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Card.js#L15-L77), where the upper half of the `DropTarget` translates to a `Before` drop while the lower half translates to an `After` drop:

```
(bounds, position) => {
  const middleY = (bounds.bottom - bounds.top) / 2;
  const relativeY = position.y - bounds.top;
  return relativeY < middleY ? DropType.Before : DropType.After;
};
```

This approach also means that each `DropTarget` could handle the `drop()` spec method in the same manner:

- get bounds of the drop target's DOM element
- get the drop position
- calculate the drop type from the bounds, position, and source
- if any drop type occurred, handle the drop action

With React DnD, we have to be careful to appropriately handle nested drop targets since we have `Field`s in a `Workbench`:

```
const configureDrop = getDropType => (props, monitor, component) => {
  // a nested element handled the drop already
  if (monitor.didDrop())
    return;

  // requires that the component attach the ref to a node property
  const { node } = component;
  if (!node) return;

  const bounds = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  const position = monitor.getClientOffset();
  const source = monitor.getItem();

  const dropType = getDropType(bounds, position, source);

  if (!dropType)
    return;

  const { onDrop, ...target } = props;
  onDrop(source, target, dropType);

  // won't be used, but need to declare that the drop was handled
  return { dropped: true };
};
```

The `Component` class would end up looking something like this:

```
@connect(...)
@DragSource(ItemTypes.FIELD, { 
  beginDrag: ({ unique, parent, attributes }) => ({ unique, parent, attributes })
}, dragCollect)
// IMPORTANT: DropTarget has to be applied first so we aren't receiving
// the wrapped DragSource component in the drop() component argument
@DropTarget(ItemTypes.FIELD, { 
  drop: configureDrop(getFieldDropType)
  canDrop: ({ parent }) => parent // don't drop if it isn't on the Workbench
}, dropCollect)
class Field extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    return (
      // ref prop used to provide access to the underlying DOM node in drop()
      <div ref={ref => this.node = ref}>
        // field stuff
      </div>
    );
}
```

Couple things to note:

Be mindful of the decorator order. `DropTarget` should wrap the component, then `DragSource` should wrap the wrapped component. This way, we have access to the correct `component` instance inside `drop()`.

The drop target's root node needs to be a native element node, not a custom component node.

Any component that will be decorated with the `DropTarget` utilizing `configureDrop()` will require that the component set its root node's DOM `ref` to a `node` property.

Since we are handling the drop in the `DropTarget`, the `DragSource` just needs to implement the `beginDrag()` method, which would just return whatever state you want mixed into your application state.

The last thing to do is handle each drop type in your reducer. Important to remember is that every time you move something around, you need to *remove* the source from its current parent (if applicable), then *insert* it into the new parent. Each action could mutate the state of up to three elements, the source's existing parent (to clean up its `children`), the source (to assign its `parent` reference), and the target's parent or the target if an `Inside` drop (to add 
to its `children`).

You also might want to consider making your state an object instead of an array, which might be easier to work with when implementing the reducer.

```
{
  AWJOPD: { ... },
  DAWPNC: { ... },
  workbench: {
    key: 'workbench',
    parent: null,
    children: [ 'DAWPNC' ]
  }
}
```

Comment: My state was an object in one version, I decided to use arrays because I find them nicer to work with. I understand I can use findDOMNode(), but this is my issue with it: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678

Comment: Please see the full exchange on the issue thread culminating in [this comment](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678#issuecomment-238090846). We need the DOM node at the time of the `drop()` call, but React DnD only provides the component props, the monitor, and the **wrapped** component. With `findDOMNode()`, getting size info is trivial; without it, not so much.

Comment: One more thing to note, the user who open the referenced issue, @gaearon, is also the author of React DnD and is listed as a contributor on the [Sortable example](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Card.js).

Comment: I know that. That example just looks like it's from [Oct 15, 2015](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/f37dc947f085baa4a2eec0bd64d27b47eac4d126/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Card.js) and the issue I referenced is from Jul 12, 2016. That's a lot of time in the JavaScript world, examples get outdated all the time. I'm trying to build something that will keep working in the long run, I don't want to be stuck in React 18 if they drop findDOMNode in 19.

Comment: So I have a basic understanding on how I could achieve something that works now, but that won't do. My understanding is that refs should be used instead, but I lack the knowledge on how to apply them to my case.

Comment: I see what you mean. I edited the answer to show how you could use React's [`ref` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) to provide access to the `component`'s underlying DOM node during `drop()`.

Comment: Kinda makes sense. This is for a side project of mine so it might take a while before I get to try this in practise, but this should help.